# R - fill missing information based on paired data

Tags: r, fill, missing-data

I am trying to fill missing cases with information based a related individual (*couple*).

My data looks like this

```
   hserial    sex age     children
1  1001041   Male  30          Yes
2  1001041 Female  32          Yes
3  1001061   Male  22           No
4  1001061 Female  21           No
5  1001091   Male  38          Yes
6  1001091 Female  37          Yes
7  1001151   Male  31           No
8  1001151 Female  27 Not eligible
9  1001161   Male  33          Yes
10 1001161 Female  35          Yes
```

So `hserial` is the *couple* identifier. Row number 8 has a missing case `Not eligible` but the information is available from the partner (row number 7).

I am trying to find a neat way to fill these missing with partner's info.

I was thinking doing something like

```
library(dplyr) 

childsum = dta %>% group_by(hserial, sex, children) %>% 
summarise(n = n()) %>% spread(sex, children)
```

I will get

```
  hserial n Male       Female
1 1001041 1  Yes          Yes
2 1001061 1   No           No
3 1001091 1  Yes          Yes
4 1001151 1   No Not eligible
5 1001161 1  Yes          Yes
```

Then I could do something like

```
childsum$Male = ifelse(childsum$Male == 'Not eligible', childsum$Female, childsum$Male)
childsum$Female = ifelse(childsum$Female == 'Not eligible', childsum$Male, childsum$Female)
```

So for every missing of `Male` fill with `Female` info and *vice versa*. 
Then merge **back** the results in order to get

```
   hserial    sex age     children
1  1001041   Male  30          Yes
2  1001041 Female  32          Yes
3  1001061   Male  22           No
4  1001061 Female  21           No
5  1001091   Male  38          Yes
6  1001091 Female  37          Yes
7  1001151   Male  31           No
8  1001151 Female  27           No
9  1001161   Male  33          Yes
10 1001161 Female  35          Yes
```

Any idea how to do this is a neat way ?

```
dta = structure(list(hserial = c(1001041, 1001041, 1001061, 1001061, 
1001091, 1001091, 1001151, 1001151, 1001161, 1001161), sex = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Male", "Female"
), class = "factor"), age = c(30, 32, 22, 21, 38, 37, 31, 27, 
33, 35), children = structure(c(5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("DNA Does not apply", "NA No answer", "NA No answer", 
"Not eligible", "Yes", "No"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("hserial", 
"sex", "age", "children"), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach which assumes that any couple (consisting of two `hserial`s) should always have the same yes/no entry in `children` unless both persons have `Not eligible` entries. Therefore, it computes per couple the `setdiff` of available `children` info and `Not eligible`. In cases where all (both) entries are "Not eligible", it returns `NA`, since I think that's a better way to handle missing values (as you know there are many specialized functions you can use with `NA`s that you cannot use the same way for `Not eligible` entries).

```
dta %>% 
  group_by(hserial) %>% 
  mutate(children = if(all(children == "Not eligible")) NA_character_ else 
                       setdiff(children, "Not eligible"))
#Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
#Groups: hserial [5]
#
#   hserial    sex   age children
#     (dbl) (fctr) (dbl)    (chr)
#1  1001041   Male    30      Yes
#2  1001041 Female    32      Yes
#3  1001061   Male    22       No
#4  1001061 Female    21       No
#5  1001091   Male    38      Yes
#6  1001091 Female    37      Yes
#7  1001151   Male    31       No
#8  1001151 Female    27       No
#9  1001161   Male    33      Yes
#10 1001161 Female    35      Yes
```